# Azkaban runtime parameter for yesterday

Tags: azkaban

According to official website, `Azkaban` only provides year-month-date for running time like:

```
${azkaban.flow.start.day}
```

Is it possible to add parameters for the day before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it with jexl by yourself.

e.g.

```
yesterday=$(new("org.joda.time.DateTime").minusDays(1).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

ref: https://github.com/azkaban/azkaban/pull/277